Very high ping and occasional packet loss on ADSL line
I've searched far and wide for over a year for this problem and i've yet to found a solution. Stack Exchange is the last straw before i cancel my DSL subscription, so please bear with me.
I have a 16 Mbps DSL subscription in a 3rd world country. I've been having occasional packet loss and very high ping that started at peak hours and now happens early in the morning too. Here are the specs and tech details, before i summarize the solutions i have tried so far.

Router is Asus DSL-AC52U
DSL Log shows Zero CRC errors. Attenuation and SNR are within normal (screenshot is included).
Ping under normal conditions is about 70-90 ms. Under unusual conditions, it goes up to 900ms at times.
Packet loss occurs especially at normal ping values up ranging from 20% up to 80% (Logs are included for both high and normal ping).
High ping happens (sometimes, and more often at peak hours) as follows: Internet drops for 2-3 seconds and then returns with 700-800ms ping. Line condition is still the same, zero CRC errors and SNR Margin/Attenuation at same value.

Solutions i have tried in the past year:

Telephone terminals at my end and at street punch-down box were cleaned several times.
Telephone line was replaced twice with new cable all the way from the punch-down box at my neighborhood level up to my place.
DSLAM (i hope i'm using the correct term) at the main distribution frame feeding the entire block where i live was also checked and tested.
Different router was tested and gave same results.
Telephone lines are located at least 50cm from the closest electrical power line.
DSL provider support assured me several times all tests were conducted and my line was in best condition available.

I have included the Router main log, PING logs and Traceroute logs at both normal and high ping, and Netstat log.
Looking forward to your answers/suggestions.
Logs are uploaded as .txt files as there are several and i'm not sure i can fit them all in my post.
https://file.io/22kOF0ioSH1Q

Does your modem or router report current traffic statistics anywhere? Specifically, the live download and upload rates (as opposed to the negotiated ADSL link rates)? This is fairly typical when trying to squeeze large amounts of upload data through a slow link (which I assume would be around 1–2 Mbps in your case?) as many routers have poor queuing algorithms.

ADSL equipment often has bufferbloat problems that cause latency spikes. Run the Waveform Bufferbloat Test and if you don't like you grade, use a site like StopLagging.com to learn your options for running a Smart Queue Management (SQM) algorithm on you router to fix bufferbloat.

@grawity_u1686 Yea, it does. It has a traffic monitor on WAN and LAN. Although, maybe i forgot to mention that the high latency happens randomly, when there aren't any other devices connected. I would be playing a PVP video game, which normally doesn't download any files during the match. Even when the game downloads files, it's merely 10-20 mbs. I run Glasswire Network Security, with the Win task manager. and both don't report high download traffic. Yes, my upload rate is 1Mbps. It should be 2Mbps but my router refuses to connect through ADSL2+ Annex M. I have it set to Annex A right now.

@grawity_u1686 I have two routers. One Tp-Link using 8Mbps connection, and the other Asus (the one currently concerned about) is 16Mbps. The Asus one has only one device connected to it via ethernet. Sometimes i even switch off the WiFi. Problem still persists. Regardless, what do i need to do about the traffic monitor? It only grabbed the last 8 hours data because i have my router scheduled to reset daily at a certain hour to hopefully keep the connection clean.

@Spiff Here are my results with the high latency.
https://www.waveform.com/tools/bufferbloat?test-id=8ca8e52a-3c20-48ca-8005-6591d0b6f6d5

@Spiff These are my results with low latency on router. All i have to do is click Save on my router's WAN settings page (with/out changing any values) few times and the ping goes back to normal from ~750ms to ~90ms. It's very bizarre.
https://www.waveform.com/tools/bufferbloat?test-id=6030a9d4-8b03-4ddb-b8fd-bff017558f63
